# Netbeans surround selection with quotes

Tags: netbeans

I want to surround the selected text with quotes or parentheses when I hit the corresponding button, not to overwrite it, which is the behavior I have observed. From what I have read so far, this is how the program usually behaves, but definitely not my case. I could not find the equivalent setting under Tools > Options. I have found the macros to surround a single word, but I want the whole selection, as would be expected in other text editors and IDEs.

Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.2

For example - the selection:

```
a string consisting of multiple words
```

Press Shift + 2 (where " is on my keyboard layout):

```
"a string consisting of multiple words"
```

Comment: It seem like all you need to do is to remap your hotkeys. Look under `Tools->Options->Keymap`

Comment: @hfontanez I just looked at all the Keymap possibilities and couldn't find any that resembles what I need. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I will have to reinstall Netbeans which I uninstalled a few days ago because I do not use it. Let me see what I can find out.

Comment: Have you had a chance to review my proposed solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK....

You were right when you said that you could not find anything close this shortcut. I looked through the entire list and there was none. The only thing close to it was to surround a single word in quotes. So, that means that ***you will have to create one shortcut to surround text selection in quotes and another with parentheses. They will be very similar, but will require two different hotkeys***.

For example, I created a shortcut to surround text selection in quotes. To do so, you have to go to `Tools -> Options -> Editor` and click `New` button

[image]

In the "New Macro Dialog" enter a name (i.e. "quote-selection") and click "OK". Then, type in `copy-to-clipboard "\"" paste-from-clipboard "\""` in the "Macro Code" text area. Lastly, click "Set Shortcut..." button and type in the exact sequence of key presses you want to use for your shortcut. Don't worry if you enter a shortcut already in use. It will warn you if you do. I chose to use `CNTL+ALT+3` because that's not in use. When you are satisfied, just click "OK" to record your shortcut. If you make a mistake in the key presses, simply click "Clear".

[image]

Then, repeat the process for surrounding with parentheses with the macro code `copy-to-clipboard "(" paste-from-clipboard ")"`. When you are done, click "Apply" and "OK".

I used Netbeans version 12.3, so I expect everything shown here should be very similar (if not identical) to 12.2.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I tried it but encountered some problems. Firstly, the macro detects my shortcut but doesn't override it, thus also inserting the letter it represents. That means it types out
`"selection""`
instead of 
`"selection"`
when I use " to trigger it.
Secondly, it triggers also when I don't have anything selected, which makes it paste whatever was in my clipboard whenever I try to insert a ". I could overcome both problems by assigning a shortcut which doesn't normally insert any character, but that defeats the purpose.

Comment: I suspect it all has to do with my german keyboard. I tried using `Alt Gr + 7` as a shortcut for the macro with brackets, since that's how I insert brackets on my layout. However, trying to enter that combination produces `Ctrl + Alt + 7` on NetBeans -- it does work if I press those buttons, but not with Alt Gr. Some research showed me this has to do with keyboard layouts (I found numerous other threads related to that, but none had the solution).

Comment: I have actually decided to use your suggestion, assigning `Alt + 2` instead of the regular Shift. That is a fair compromise and avoids some headache. Same for the brackets. Kinda lame but works! Thanks again